# Not able to set up ANT Migration Tool

Tags: ant, migration-tool

I am trying to set up the ANT Migration Tool on my Windows Laptop (Windows 10 64 bit).
I have set the ANT_HOME, JAVA_HOME, and PATH but still, I am getting the error

```
'ant' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

[image]

Can you guys please help me here. I am not getting what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks
Nirav

Comment: Have you restarted your laptop since modifying `%PATH%`? Something like that (perhaps simply logging off of your account and logging in again is sufficient, but you'd still end up closing all open programs) is generally required to allow new/modified environment variables to take effect.

Comment: That said, the migration tool using ANT and package.xml is old. Is there a reason why you're not using the Salesforce CLI (sfdx)?

Comment: I second Derek here - you really should move over to using the sfdx CLI if at all possible. It is actively maintained and enhanced unlike the legacy Ant tasks which will be left to wither and die. If you have or want to use Ant, you can still use sfdx from it via the standard exec task (this is the approach we have taken).